# Is there an easy way to locate handles / tunnels on a closed 3d triangle mesh?

Tags: graphics, mesh, topology

So I'm trying to use a boundary-based method to do mesh segmentation on a mesh with a random number of small handles. I already have a rough boundary, only need to refine it to make sure it stays below the lowest points of all the tunnels in the mesh. So I need to know where the tunnels are.

[image]

I found a few papers computing handle and tunnel loops, which are a bit intimidating given that I don't have a solid topology background.

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85163/finding-the-topological-genus-of-a-triangulated-surface

Comment: I mean to locate genus, not to count the number

Comment: Then you need to be more precise in your wording. The topological genus is an integer associated with a surface, and cannot be "located". You probably mean something else.

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: Your image doesn't show triangles.

Comment: Er, how are the triangles related to this? If you are wondering about the scale, I'd say there are hundreds of triangles in this bit of mesh, it's a uniform mesh. If we take the side length of the triangles as a unit, this one hole is like a cylinder with a diameter of about 8 side length in the base and a height of 8 side length

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to know a certain part of the boundary of your triangulated 3D domain. This cannot be done because, in 3D, there is nothing that topologically separates a "hole" from other parts of the boundary. In other words: All boundaries are holes.

Answer (score 0):

I found no simple way to directly locate handles. However, shape diameter function can reflect whether a vertex is near to a hole or not to a large extent if there's no noise inside of the mesh.